# In R I have a column that contains the index (or column name) I want to pull from in a new column. How do I do this?

Tags: r, join, z-index, lookup

I basically want to do a lookup or similar to an INDEX/MATCH in Excel but in R. My data contains a column which refers to the row number I want from the lookup table and a column which refers to the column number that I want from the lookup table. Here's an example of my data:

| ID | Desired Row | Desired Column |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 5 | 2 |

and then the lookup table goes:

| name | city | food |
| --- | --- | --- |
| john | boston | pizza |
| mike | new york | pasta |
| sarah | chicago | hoagie |
| sam | los angeles | sushi |
| kelly | dallas | ice cream |

I want to create a new column that returns row 4, col 1 = sam; row 2 col 3 = pasta; row 5 col 2 = dallas.

If it would be easier I also have a field that contains that exact column name that I want to look in and have the lookup table joined in. so for example

| ID | Desired Row | Desired Column | Desired Output |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | this row | name | john |
| 2 | this row | food | pasta |
| 3 | this row | city | chicago |

I've tried using df[row,column] where I've used variables as the row and column and instead of giving me one new column it gives me a column for every possible outcome

I've also tried using paste() to reference a specific column using text, and adding a variable at the end which would get me to the correct column (makes sense in my exact context where the columns names are numbered).

Comment: `lookup_table[as.matrix(data[, c('DesiredRow', 'DesiredColumn')])]`

Comment: @Onyambu what package is lookup_table in? or, wait is it literally the lookup table that I want to use?

Comment: `lookup_table` is not a function but rather your lookup table

Comment: @Onyambu I see so, as.matrix(data[, c('DesiredRow', 'DesiredColumn')]) works and returns a table of the rows and column indices I want. However, when I add the lookup table[ ] I get this: Error: Subscript `as.matrix(data[, c("desired row", "desired column")])` is a matrix, it must be of type logical

Comment: Check the solution given below

Comment: thanks @Onyambu you've been a huge help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be more elegant/faster ways, but in base R, you could index using `sapply` or a `for` loop. I am also including an approach using these data based off of @Onyambu's comment (which is more elegant).

If you have these data:

```
lu <- data.frame(id = 1:3, 
                 row = c(4,2,5), 
                 col = c(1,3,2))

df <- read.table(text = "name   city    food
john    boston  pizza
mike    new_york    pasta
sarah   chicago hoagie
sam los_angeles sushi
kelly   dallas  ice_cream", h = TRUE)
```

You can do:

```
want <- data.frame(id = lu$id)

for(i in seq_len(nrow(want))){
  want[i,"desired_value"] <- df[lu$row[i], lu$col[i]]
}

# or

want$desired_value <- sapply(seq_len(nrow(want)), function(i) df[lu$row[i], lu$col[i]])

# Or per Onyambu's comment:
want$desired_value <- df[as.matrix(lu[,c("row", "col")])]
```

All return the following output:

```
#> want
#  id desired_value
#1  1           sam
#2  2         pasta
#3  3        dallas
```

Comment: forgive me, I'm still new to R. in the 2nd solution you lost me at 

\(x) df[lu$row[x], lu$col[x]]

do I literally use "x" or is that a substitute for the column names?

the 3rd solution from Onyambu isn't working because I get 
Error: Subscript `as.matrix(data[, c("desired row", "desired column")])` is a matrix, it must be of type logical.

Comment: @stacktuary23 in this context, `sapply` does the same as a `for` loop (it takes the first argument and iterates through a defined function) - I've edited it to make the relationship between `sapply` and the `for` loop clearer.  (yes, you would literally use `x`, though I changed it to `i` to show the similarities).

Comment: As for the approach by Onyambu, it is difficult to provide help without your actual data. If you edit your question to include `dput` of the above tables, ie, `dput(lookup_table)`  folks can provide more specific help

Comment: the For loop is working perfectly thanks so much!